# Azure Users Sign-ins shows proxy IP address instead of the real IP

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to find a way to display the real IPs of VMs a user has tried to sign in instead of the proxy's IP in the "Sign-ins" section of each user.
For example if user "max" tried to sign in to a vm that has the IP '10.0.0.1' then when I go to the Sign-ins section of user max it will show me that this user tried to log in at 10.0.0.1 and not at the proxy IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that unless your VM is directly to connect to the Internet without any proxy. Also, in your example, the IP address 10.0.0.1 is a private address that does not route on the Internet.

To display the IP address is a bit to rely on the networking environment where your VMs. From the [Sign-in activity reports in the Azure Active Directory portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#sign-ins-data-shortcuts), currently Azure tries best effort to convert the IP address to a physical location where the computer located as mapping IP addresses is complicated by the fact that mobile providers and VPNs issue IP addresses from central pools that are often very far from where the client device is actually used.

> IP addresses are issued in such a way that there is no definitive
>   connection between an IP address and where the computer with that
>   address is physically located. Mapping IP addresses is complicated by
>   the fact that mobile providers and VPNs issue IP addresses from
>   central pools that are often very far from where the client device is
>   actually used. Currently in Azure AD reports, converting IP address to
>   a physical location is a best effort based on traces, registry data,
>   reverse look ups and other information.